# Setting background color with JavaScript breaks the CSS hover behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I'm trying to create a menu where the currently selected (clicked) element has a different background color than the other elements (I'm trying to achieve this using JavaScript). I also use the CSS `:hover` pseudoclass to make the hovered element stand out by highlighting it. However, I have encountered a strange problem: when I set the background color of any element with JavaScript, its CSS hover behavior no longer works. That is, I can't highlight the element by hovering it anymore. I have checked that in Firefox and Chromium. This is the case for both jQuery and plain JavaScript.

The code is below. I have simplified it a lot to narrow down the problem. First try hovering any of the menu items, then click the "Set background color" link and hover one of the menu elements again. What I expect is the element getting red (#f00) when hovered, regardless of whether the "Set background color" button was clicked or not. **For jsfiddle links, go to the bottom.**

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            p#links a {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 80px;
                height: 22px;
                line-height: 22px;
                background-color: #00f;
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            p#links a:hover {
                background-color: #f00;
            }       
        </style>
        <title>Background color</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="links">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </p>
        <a href="#" id="setbgcolor">Set background color</a>

        <script>
            document.getElementById('setbgcolor').onclick = function() {
                var p = document.getElementById('links');
                var elements = p.getElementsByTagName('a');
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
                    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <style>
            p#links a {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 80px;
                height: 22px;
                line-height: 22px;
                background-color: #00f;
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            p#links a:hover {
                background-color: #f00;
            }       
        </style>
        <title>Background color</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="links">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </p>
        <a href="#" id="setbgcolor">Set background color</a>

        <script>
            $('a#setbgcolor').click(function() {
                $('p#links a').css('background-color', '#ff0');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here are jsfiddle.net links for the purpose of convenience:
Pure JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/5yQFM/1/
jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/5yQFM/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery `css()` method maps onto the `style` property which maps onto the `style` attribute.

Rules inside a `style` attribute are more specific then rules in a stylesheet, so will always come after them in [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

Instead of altering the CSS on the element directly, alter it by [changing the classes](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) the element belongs to and having a pre-prepared stylesheet.

Comment: i like the fact that you're explaining it, though i have a hard time to follow... how would your recommendation look "code-wise"? (note, i'm not the OP, just curious)

Answer (score 6):

you need to use `!important` on hover, basically it will increase its priority.

Try this,

```
p#links a:hover {
    background-color: #f00 !important;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5yQFM/4/)

---

As Quentin said it looks like a dirty one, so in that situation we can make use of the class priority concepts.

HTML:

```
<a class='normal' href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class='normal' href="#">Link 1</a>
```

CSS:

```
.normal { background-color: blue; } 
.abnormal{ background-color: yellow; }

.normal:hover { background-color: #f00; }
```

JS:

```
$('p#links a').attr('class', 'abnormal normal');
```

### [DEMO Non-Dirty one](http://jsfiddle.net/5yQFM/5/)

Comment: Quick but dirty. Avoid `!important` rules. They only go one layer deep. You get better control (and separation of concerns) by careful application of specificity.

Comment: @Quentin yes sure, I thought , for handling this kind of situations the `!important` is made for. :)

Comment: Upvoted.  Quick and NOT dirty on this specific situation.

Answer (score 5):

How about **keeping the style in CSS** and not in Javascript, by adding classes ?

so the line :

```
elements[i].style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
```

Change to

```
elements[i].className = 'myClassForBackgrounds';
```

or in the jQ version

```
$('p#links a').css('background-color', '#ff0');
```

to :

```
$('p#links a').addClass('myClassForBackgrounds');
```

---

That way you can set your `:hover` as you would normally

```
#links a:hover, .myClassForBackgrounds:hover { background-color:#ff0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for a more simple answer, in able to just re-enable css rules just have it toggle between the color and "", so

```
document.getElementById("id").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 125, 15)";
```

would be if the element wasn't already colored via javascript.
Now, if your element was already colored the code would look like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.backgroundColor = "";
```

That re-enables CSS so then your selectors will work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by doing this:

I set a onmouseover event to change the background color to what the hover color is.

I set a onmouseout event to change the background color to the default color.

This way I have set a hover event with pure javascript